# Core 3.1 EF 6 in Database-first: unable to determine the many-to-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1

I have a problem with using EF "database-first" in Core 3.1 with many-to-many relationship.
There are two tables: ResourcesAZEZ and AsezPoolFileStore
And third table AsezPoolFileLink, which contains only two columns: idRes and idFile

Auto-generated code of that classes:

```
 public partial class AsezPoolFileStore
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public AsezPoolFileStore()
        {
            this.ResourcesAZEZs = new HashSet<ResourcesAZEZ>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string fileId { get; set; }
        public string filePath { get; set; }
    
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<ResourcesAZEZ> ResourcesAZEZs { get; set; }
    }

public partial class ResourcesAZEZ
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public ResourcesAZEZ()
        {
            this.AsezDictResLinks = new HashSet<AsezDictResLink>();
            this.AsezPoolFileStores = new HashSet<AsezPoolFileStore>();
        }
    
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string id_outer { get; set; }
        public string number_customer { get; set; }
        public string material_text_full { get; set; }
        public string mark { get; set; }
        public string requirements { get; set; }
        public string mark_main { get; set; }
        public string unit { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> quantity { get; set; }
        public string producer_text { get; set; }
        public string delivery_date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> price { get; set; }
        public string currency { get; set; }
....
    
        public virtual AsezBSCatalog AsezBSCatalog { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AsezDictResLink> AsezDictResLinks { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<AsezPoolFileStore> AsezPoolFileStores { get; set; }
    }
```

And in model.edmx:

```
          <EntitySetMapping Name="AsezPoolFileStore">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="BCR_ASEZModel.AsezPoolFileStore">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="AsezPoolFileStore">
                <ScalarProperty Name="id" ColumnName="id" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="fileId" ColumnName="fileId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="filePath" ColumnName="filePath" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>

<EntitySetMapping Name="ResourcesAZEZs">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="BCR_ASEZModel.ResourcesAZEZ">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="ResourcesAZEZ">
                <ScalarProperty Name="winner_okved" ColumnName="winner_okved" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="winner_kpp" ColumnName="winner_kpp" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="winner_inn" ColumnName="winner_inn" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="winner_id_asez" ColumnName="winner_id_asez" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="okved2" ColumnName="okved2" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="okpd2" ColumnName="okpd2" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="dictId" ColumnName="dictId" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="numberpubl" ColumnName="numberpubl" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="previous_ppid" ColumnName="previous_ppid" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="number_cgg" ColumnName="number_cgg" />
...
                <ScalarProperty Name="id_outer" ColumnName="id_outer" />
                <ScalarProperty Name="id" ColumnName="id" />
              </MappingFragment>
            </EntityTypeMapping>
          </EntitySetMapping>


          <AssociationSetMapping Name="AsezPoolFileLink" TypeName="BCR_ASEZModel.AsezPoolFileLink" StoreEntitySet="AsezPoolFileLink">
            <EndProperty Name="ResourcesAZEZ">
              <ScalarProperty Name="id" ColumnName="idRes" />
            </EndProperty>
            <EndProperty Name="AsezPoolFileStore">
              <ScalarProperty Name="id" ColumnName="idFile" />
            </EndProperty>
          </AssociationSetMapping>
```

Everything look goodm the same as in the [article](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entity-relationships.aspx).
But for some reasn I'm getting error:

> System.InvalidOperationException   HResult=0x80131509   Message=Unable
> to determine the relationship represented by navigation property
> 'ResourcesAZEZ.AsezPoolFileStores' of type
> 'ICollection'. Either manually configure the
> relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]'
> attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore   StackTrace:    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidatePropertyMapping(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Infrastructure.NpgsqlModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ValidatingConvention.ProcessModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder
> modelBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder modelBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.FinalizeModel()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__7_3(IServiceProvider p)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope
> serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite
> singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()  at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.CheckState() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() at System.Linq.Queryable.Select[TSource,TResult](IQueryable`1 source,
> Expression`1 selector)    at
> KROSS_Core.BLL.ASEZ.GSResourcesAZEZ.GetFilterFieldValues(String
> entityName) in C:\Estimates Core\KROSS
> Core\BLL\ASEZ\GSResourcesAZEZ.cs:line 1550    at
> KROSS_Core.Controllers.GlobalSearchAsezController.AsezFiltersRead(HttpContext
> context) in C:\Estimates Core\KROSS
> Core\Controllers\GlobalSearchAsezController.cs:line 489    at
> KROSS_Core.Controllers.GlobalSearchAsezController.Post() in
> C:\Estimates Core\KROSS
> Core\Controllers\GlobalSearchAsezController.cs:line 70    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object
> target, Object[] parameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
> mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
> arguments)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I reconfigure relationship to make it working? Or where I can add [NotMapped] attribute in this database-first model? Appreciate for any help!

Answer (score 1):

NM relationships in EFCore are a bit tricky. I see you have both `ICollection<ResourcesAZEZ>` property on `AsezPoolFileStore` and `ICollection<AsezPoolFileStore>` on `ResourcesAZEZ` this is not supported, as you need to have an "relationship entity", which I guess is `AsezPoolFileLink`.

So you should have a `ICollection<AsezPoolFileLink>` on both entities. Later you can map those entities to you application model or domain and remove the `AsezPoolFileLink` intermediate structure, so you can end having the collections you have now. Or always work with the "relationship entity" in between your two entites, up to you.

About your question on how to use `[NotMapped]` attribute, you do it like this:

```
[NotMapped]
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
public virtual ICollection<ResourcesAZEZ> ResourcesAZEZs { get; set; }
```

This will make any property with this attribute to not being mapped to a field in the database by EFCore.

You can achieve the same functionality using `FluentAPI` by creating an override of `void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)` method of your `DbContext` like

```
public class SomeDbContext : DbContext
{
    public SomeDbContext(DbContextOptions<SomeDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ResourcesAZEZ>()
        .Ignore(r => r.AsezPoolFileStores);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ResourcesAZEZ>()
        .HasMany(r => r.AsezDictResLinks)
        .WithOne(l => l.Resource);
    }
}
```

Official documentation on modeling with efcore can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/

Comment: You said "I see you have both ICollection<ResourcesAZEZ> property on AsezPoolFileStore and ICollection<AsezPoolFileStore> on ResourcesAZEZ this is wrong, and EFCore is unable to determine the relationship automatically.", but it was created automatically when I created model from database... If I trying to change to ICollection<AsezPoolFileLink>, it says that it is not defined... Do I need to create it manually inside the model? Also there is not table showing on model with the name AsezPoolFileLink, it shows just line * to *.

Comment: It might have created that but its not supported: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many From those docs: Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

Comment: So you can't have entity A with a collection of Bs and entity B with a collection of As, you need to create a C entity with a AId and BId and make entity A have a collection of Cs and entity B have a collection of Cs, then configure one-to-many relations between A(n)-C(1) and C(1)-B(n). There's no other way of doing an NM relationship with efcore as of today.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! That's really weird that it creates such model, but can't support it. But I have no idea how to detach that table AsezPoolFileLink now from the model to make it separate table and class.. Now it is in folder "Associations" and I can't remove it and make single entity by the "update from database wizard" or even manually... Is there any trick to add that entities separate?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really know what you're refering to in your comment. I don't know the structure of your project besides what you provided, sorry.